# SQL Join using aggregated string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have a table in SQL Server that looks like this:

| AGGREGATE_KEY | Value_1 |
| --- | --- |
| A,B | FOO |

And I want to join that table to another table that looks like this

| KEY | Value_2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | DAH |

To achieve the following output:

| AGGREGATE_KEY | Value_1 | Value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A,B | FOO | DAH |

Comment: You go and find the person that decided to put a comma delimited list of values in a single column and make them fix that nonsense. If they refuse, then threaten them with whatever power you have. If that doesn't work then you can split your delimited string into individual records with which you can do your join using [`STRING_SPLIT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) but the performance isn't going to be amazing. If you are on an older version (pre 2016) then it's going to get ugly.

Comment: This is clearly a less than ideal scenario where I have to find a way to fit a square peg into a round hole. Admittedly you should never, ever put a comma delimited list of values into a single column, and have that column function as a key to another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you [normalized your table design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/database-normalization-description). It is recommended and would make your queries and joins more efficient.

With the current shared example, you may use `LIKE` to match both fields. `CONCAT` may be used to add the wildcards to assist with pattern matching.

> ```
> SELECT 
>     t1.*, 
>     t2.Value_2, 
>     CONCAT(',',t1.AGGREGATE_KEY,',') as NEW_T1_AGGREGATE_KEY,
>     CONCAT('%,',t2.[KEY],',%')  as NEW_T2_KEY
> FROM t1
> INNER JOIN t2 ON CONCAT(',',t1.AGGREGATE_KEY,',')  LIKE CONCAT('%,',t2.[KEY],',%') 
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> AGGREGATE_KEY | Value_1 | Value_2 | NEW_T1_AGGREGATE_KEY | NEW_T2_KEY
> :------------ | :------ | :------ | :------------------- | :---------
> A,B           | FOO     | DAH     | ,A,B,                | %,A,%
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     t1.*, 
>     t2.Value_2
> FROM t1
> INNER JOIN t2 ON CONCAT(',',t1.AGGREGATE_KEY,',')  LIKE CONCAT('%,',t2.[KEY],',%') 
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> AGGREGATE_KEY | Value_1 | Value_2
> :------------ | :------ | :------
> A,B           | FOO     | DAH
> ```

*See working demo db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=10090b9cc24d7da21291a577ac01823e)*

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on my comment. If you are stuck doing this because you can't fix the data (because the schema really is **broken** as it is) and you are on a newer version SQL Server, you can use `string_split()` to split your delimited string into individual records before joining. If your data is large though, this is going to be slow.

```
SELECT 
  t1.aggregate_key, 
  t1.value_1,
  t2.value_2
FROM t1
   CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(AGGREGATE_KEY, ',') keys
   INNER JOIN t2 ON keys.value = t2.[key];


+---------------+---------+---------+
| aggregate_key | value_1 | value_2 |
+---------------+---------+---------+
| A,B           | FOO     | DAH     |
+---------------+---------+---------+
```